# Assigning Values so that Sum of Each Rows and Columns in Matrix is the Same

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I have an adjacency matrix below (both column & headers are userIDs) with values either 0s or 1s. The value 1 denotes that the 1st user knows the 2nd user and vice versa (e.g User 0 knows User 1 and vice versa) whilst the value 0 denotes both users do not know each other.

Matrix Table

[image: 1]

The matrix has the shape of (N, N) which is (5, 5) and that:
Matrix[i][j] = 1 / d[j] if the userID = i knows userID = j.
d[j] is the total number of users the user indexed by j knows.
The sum of each rows and columns is supposed to be 1.

Based on the codes below, I've managed to get the sum of each columns to be 1 however, I'm unable to figure how to manipulate the values such that the sum of each rows will also be 1.

```
matrix = [[0, 1, 0 ,1, 0],
          [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
          [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
          [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
          [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]]

d = np.sum(matrix, axis = 0) # sum the value of 1 in each column

for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix)):
        if matrix[i][j] == 1:
            matrix[i][j] = 1 / d[j]
        else:
            matrix[i][j] = 0
```

Below is my result reflecting sum of each columns as 1.

Matrix Result

[image: 2]

Appreciate all of your guidance.

Comment: `np.array(matrix) / d`

Comment: The original `matrix` is symmetric. Is this required for the result matrix, too?

Comment: @MichaelButscher I believe the result `matrix` shouldn't be symmetric.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @Psidom. I've tried implementing the following:
`np.array(matrix) / d` but it still reflecting the same result as `matrix[i][j] = 1 / d[j]`

Comment: Maybe (probably) there exists already an algorithm (or library) for this which I don't know (maybe `sympy` could work). I think it would need a recursive function with backtracking which finds a row or column with fewest unmodified values, change values to fulfill condition for this row/column, mark values as modified and repeat until it is either solved or not solvable (then the backtracking is used).

Answer (score 0):

One option is to iterate setting row sums to 1 then setting column sums to 1.  This fails if there is any column or row summing to zero.  If only one item is set in any row it forces a lot of zeros and may not converge instead alternating between two states.  See the last example.

```
import numpy as np

def normalise( arr, loops = 30 ): 
    """ arr is the original array
        loops is to count how many times to iterate before giving up.
    """
    calc = arr.copy() 
    col_sum = calc.sum( axis = 0 ) # Sum each column
    for i in range( loops ):
        calc = calc / col_sum      # Normalise each column to sum to 1.
        row_sum = calc.sum( axis = 1 )  # Sum each row
        calc = calc / row_sum[ :, None ]  # Normalise each row.sum() to 1.
        col_sum = calc.sum( axis = 0 )  # Sum each column
        if np.all( np.isclose( col_sum, 1., atol = 1e-10, rtol = 1e-10 )): 
            break # Exit loop if each column sums close to 1.
    return calc
```

The `isclose` tolerances can be chosen for however close to 1. is acceptable.

```
matrix = np.array( [[0, 1, 0 ,1, 0], 
                    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0], 
                    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1], 
                    [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], 
                    [0, 0, 1, 1, 0]] )

normalise( matrix )                                                    
# array([[0.  , 0.75, 0.  , 0.25, 0.  ],
#        [0.75, 0.  , 0.  , 0.25, 0.  ],
#        [0.  , 0.  , 0.  , 0.25, 0.75],
#        [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.  , 0.25],
#        [0.  , 0.  , 0.75, 0.25, 0.  ]])
```

This shows a problem:

```
mat1   = np.array( [[0, 1, 0 ,1, 0],   # = 2
                    [1, 0, 0, 1, 0],   # = 2
                    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],   # = 1 !!
                    [1, 1, 1, 0, 1],   # = 4
                    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]] ) # = 1 !!
# Sums to            2  2  1  4  1 

normalise( mat1 )                                                      

# array([[ 0.,    1.,  0., ~0.0, 0. ],  = 1.
#        [ 1.,    0.,  0., ~0.0, 0. ],  = 1.
#        [ 0.,    0.,  0.,  1.0, 0. ],  = 1.
#        [~0.0, ~0.0, 0.5,  0.0, 0.5],  = 1.
#        [ 0.,    0.,  0.,  1.0, 0. ]]) = 1.

# Sums     1.     1.  0.5   2.0  0.5
```

Next 50% iteration

```
# array([[ 0.,    1.,  0., ~0.0, 0. ],  = 1.
#        [ 1.,    0.,  0., ~0.0, 0. ],  = 1.
#        [ 0.,    0.,  0.,  0.5, 0. ],  = 0.5
#        [~0.0, ~0.0,  1.,  0.0, 1. ],  = 2.
#        [ 0.,    0.,  0.,  0.5, 0. ]]) = 0.5.

# Sums     1.     1.   1.   1.   1.
```

Each iteration alternates between these two states